# Regular expression to check invalid input

Tags: java

I need to parse a a string which contains the query for the database.

The valid strings can be the following :

- Status:OPEN,PENDING
- Status:OPEN
- Status:PENDING
- Status:REJECTED
- type:SMALL
- type:BIG
- weight>100

The following is not valid :

- `weight:100<PENDING`

My first try was this in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+)(|,)*(\\w+)*$");
```

Obviously, it fails to parse the last statement correctly.

Comment: I don't think a regular expression is the appropriate tool for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think that validating this with a regexpression is a hrad thing.
But you can try this expression:

```
"([\\w]+)(:(([A-Z]+)|([A-Z]+,([A-Z]+)))|(>[0-9]+))"
```

It worked for me in a online regexpression tester for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

I created this expression for your requirement:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((Status:(OPEN|PENDING|OPEN,PENDING|REJECTED))|(type:(SMALL|BIG))|(weight[<>]\\d+))");
```

anything else matches invalid status, types, etc.

For example:

These are all invalid:

```
Status>100
type:REJECTED
weight:100
```

---

Hope this helps!